# Do i need to cram these weird things in Zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

For the past 2 days i am struggling with Zend. It has such a strange application structure and so many global functions. Do i need to cram all these global functions? even for setting a simple doctype, i have to go to some bootstrap file and set things there. If i keep doing this sort of silly things when will i complete my application? I have worked with Asp.Net and JSF and after working with such brilliant technologies i feel working with PHP is a real pain(Had it not been in our course curriculum, i would have dumped Zend since when). I spent 2 days completely trying to run a simple HelloWorld page. Why do i have to put simple things at weird places? They have created so many classes with strange names and force us to follow a specific structure. I mean just for putting doctype why should i put it in bootstrap class? (Ya, i know because the framework says so).

I am afraid someday they will ask me if i want to use html tags in page, i will again need to configure in their silly classes. They may be they will ask me if i want to run my application, i will again have to set some property's value in their classes else it won't run.

Point is, how am i supposed to remember them all? How many constants, how many functions? Is this my memory test working with Zend? People say Zend is the best framework out there but i feel it is really a pain. You have to keep playing with configurations until you can play no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend really isn't substantially more complicated than, say, a struts + appfuse + hibernate stack. The reason that it has that many "global functions" (my recollection is that its "global functions" are more Singleton accessors) is because it is attempting to make your life easier: instead of remembering the syntax for declaring that you're dealing with HTML strict or XHTML, it provides a simplified means for accomplishing the same thing. More importantly, though, staying within the framework means that you can spend more time working on the logic of the code and you will not need to worry about assembling the final output to the browser.

And, I don't know who you've been talking to, but it most certainly is not the "best". It has the best libraries, and it has a very good company funding it, but that does not make it the, "best."

Personally, I find that Zend does some things really well -- they have a great validation library, and the logging syntax is far cleaner and clearer than, say, log4j.

On the other hand, I feel that the Zend framework is unnecessarily bulky. Symfony is my choice for larger projects and CodeIgniter for smaller ones.

As a final note: don't judge a language by a framework.

Comment: - Thanks! but i am no more in PHP world and that is the best part. I am now into .Net.

Answer (score 0):

It can take awhile to get used to, but once you do, it's quite nice.

Here are a few nice quickstarts/tutorials:

- http://zendframework.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html
- http://www.docstoc.com/docs/854686/Zend-framework-tutorial
- http://www.harikt.com/content/simple-blog-using-zend-framework-19